# missing column after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe `df`. I group it by 3 columns, and count the results. When I do this I lose some information, specifically, the `name` column. This column is mapped 1:1 with the `desk_id` column. Is there anyway to include both in my final dataframe?

here is the dataframe:

```
   shift_id    shift_start_time      shift_end_time        name                   end_time       desk_id  shift_hour
0  37423064 2014-01-17 08:00:00 2014-01-17 12:00:00  Adam Scott 2014-01-17 10:16:41.040000  15557987           2
1  37423064 2014-01-17 08:00:00 2014-01-17 12:00:00  Adam Scott 2014-01-17 10:16:41.096000  15557987           2
2  37423064 2014-01-17 08:00:00 2014-01-17 12:00:00  Adam Scott 2014-01-17 10:52:17.402000  15557987           2
3  37423064 2014-01-17 08:00:00 2014-01-17 12:00:00  Adam Scott 2014-01-17 11:06:59.083000  15557987           3
4  37423064 2014-01-17 08:00:00 2014-01-17 12:00:00  Adam Scott 2014-01-17 08:27:57.998000  15557987           0
```

I group it like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['desk_id', 'shift_id', 'shift_hour']).size()
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
```

And here is the result, missing the `name` column.

```
    desk_id  shift_id  shift_hour  0
0  14468690  37729081           0  7
1  14468690  37729081           1  3
2  14468690  37729081           2  6
3  14468690  37729081           3  5
4  14468690  37729082           0  5
```

Also, anyway to rename the count column as 'count' instead of '0'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `'name'` in `groupby` by groups:

```
In [43]:

grouped = df.groupby(['desk_id', 'shift_id', 'shift_hour', 'name']).size()
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
grouped.columns=np.where(grouped.columns==0, 'count', grouped.columns) #replace the default 0 to 'count'
print grouped
    desk_id  shift_id  shift_hour        name  count
0  15557987  37423064           0  Adam Scott      1
1  15557987  37423064           2  Adam Scott      3
2  15557987  37423064           3  Adam Scott      1
```

If the name-to-id relationship is a many-to-one type, say we have a pete scott for the same set of data, the result will become:

```
    desk_id  shift_id  shift_hour        name  count
0  15557987  37423064           0  Adam Scott      1
1  15557987  37423064           0  Pete Scott      1
2  15557987  37423064           2  Adam Scott      3
3  15557987  37423064           2  Pete Scott      3
4  15557987  37423064           3  Adam Scott      1
5  15557987  37423064           3  Pete Scott      1
```

Comment: is it not grouping by this term again? If it wasn't a 1:1 mapping between `name` and `desk_id` would this still give me what I want?

Comment: See edit. The result will have the other names, of the same desk_id or shift_id, as well.

Comment: So, if I wanted to include `shift_start_time` in the final result as well. Adding to this to the groupby list is fine? even though I don't really want to group by this column?