# how to aggregate only the numerical columns in a mixed dtypes dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have a mixed `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                     'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                     'C' : pd.Timestamp('20180101'),
                     'D' : np.random.rand(10),
                     'F' : 'foo' })

df
Out[12]: 
     A          B          C         D    F
0  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.592533  foo
1  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.819248  foo
2  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.298035  foo
3  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.330128  foo
4  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.371705  foo
5  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.541246  foo
6  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.976108  foo
7  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.423069  foo
8  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.863764  foo
9  1.0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  0.037085  foo
```

I would like to aggregate my numerical columns, but keep also the non-numerical ones.
If I do a `gropuby` followed by `agg`.
I get:

```
df.groupby('B').agg(np.median)
Out[13]: 
              A         D
B                        
2013-01-02  1.0  0.482157
```

which is fine, and I know is desired behavior as the other dtypes probably raise exceptions during np.median, but I would like to get also my original column `F` with value `foo`, as well as `C` with `2018-01-01`

So far, I have solved with a custom wrapper to my numerical aggregation functions e.g. if I wanted to do a nanmean over my dataframe:

```
def my_nan_median(x):
    if isinstance(x.values[0], np.datetime64):
        return np.min(x) # let the first datetime pass! 
    elif isinstance(x.values[0], str):
        return x.values[0] # let the strings pass!
    else:
        return np.nanmedian(x)
```

but it looks awful.
What is the right way to do so?

Comment: What about grouping on all columns?
`df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'F']).agg(np.median).reset_index()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing column after pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456365/missing-column-after-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `select_dtypes`:

```
df.groupby(list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]))).agg(np.median).reset_index()
```

Or something like this:

```
df1 = df.groupby('B',as_index=False).agg(np.median)
pd.concat([df1,df.drop_duplicates(['B']).drop(list(df1),1).reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

If 'C', 'F' are the same for each value of 'B', then you can include it in the groupby columns, like this:

```
df.groupby(['B','C','F']).agg(np.median).reset_index()
```

Or as @BradSolomn suggests:

```
df.groupby(['B','C','F'], as_index=False).agg(np.median)
```

Output:

```
           B          C    F    A         D
0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  foo  1.0  0.392723
```

If not, then you'll need to aggregrate 'C', 'F' somehow for example get the get the first value from 'C', 'F'

```
df.groupby('B').agg({'D':np.median,'A':np.median,'C':'first','F':'last'}).reset_index() 

           B          C    F    A         D
0 2013-01-02 2018-01-01  foo  1.0  0.392723
```

Comment: Seems to be the right fix here, although I'd note this behavior was [explicitly changed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2700) early on.  So the short answer is any dtype not supporting the aggregated function (median) will be dropped.  Also, just `df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'F']).median()` would work here and you can specify `as_index=False` instead of resetting.

Comment: thanks this is actually very close to what I needed. However, what if I have thousands of columns, can use lists in the agg dictionary e.g. .agg{my_numerical_columns_list: my_fun} ?

Comment: @Liborio  Wen's solution has it.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me.

```
numerics = [col for col in df.columns 
    if isinstance(df[col].loc[0], (int, float, complex)))]

df.groupby('grouping field')[numerics].agg([np.mean, np.median])
```

Actually, this can fail if the first entry in NaN. I found a better way: use [df.select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

df.groupby('grouping_field')[numeric_cols].agg([np.mean,np.median])
```